# How can I turn an R data frame into a simple, unstyled html table?

Tags: html, r, html-table

Let's say I have a data frame in **R**. I'd like to write it to a file as a simple HTML table. Just the <table>, <tr>, and <td> tags.

So far this seems harder than it should be. Right now I'm trying to use R2THML like so:

```
HTML(dataframe, file=outpath, append=FALSE)
```

But then I get a ugly, html-styled file that might look like so:

```
<table cellspacing=0 border=1>
<caption align=bottom class=captiondataframe></caption>
<tr><td>
    <table border=0 class=dataframe>
    <tbody> 
    <tr class= firstline > 
        <th>&nbsp;  </th>
        <th>name  </th>
        <th>donations  </th>
        <th>clicks  </th>
            ...
    </tr> 
<tr> 
<td class=firstcolumn>1
</td>
<td class=cellinside>Black.text
</td>
...
</tbody>
</table>
 </td></table>
 <br>
```

Is there a way to get output that's simpler (without specifying border, headings, captions, etc. Without outputting a table *inside* another table)? Or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: I've never used it for `HTML` but I know `xtable` is a good package (I use it for `latex`) that has an `HTML` option.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `xtable` package can generate HTML output as well as LaTeX output.

```
# install.packages("xtable")
library("xtable")
sample_table <- mtcars[1:3,1:3]
print(xtable(sample_table), type="html", file="example.html")
```

gives, in the file `example.html`:

```
<!-- html table generated in R 3.0.1 by xtable 1.7-1 package -->
<!-- Fri Jul 19 09:08:15 2013 -->
<TABLE border=1>
<TR> <TH>  </TH> <TH> mpg </TH> <TH> cyl </TH> <TH> disp </TH>  </TR>
  <TR> <TD align="right"> Mazda RX4 </TD> <TD align="right"> 21.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 6.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 160.00 </TD> </TR>
  <TR> <TD align="right"> Mazda RX4 Wag </TD> <TD align="right"> 21.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 6.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 160.00 </TD> </TR>
  <TR> <TD align="right"> Datsun 710 </TD> <TD align="right"> 22.80 </TD> <TD align="right"> 4.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 108.00 </TD> </TR>
   </TABLE>
```

This could be further simplified with more options to `xtable` and `print.xtable`:

```
print(xtable(sample_table, align="llll"), 
      type="html", html.table.attributes="")
```

gives

```
<!-- html table generated in R 3.0.1 by xtable 1.7-1 package -->
<!-- Fri Jul 19 09:13:33 2013 -->
<TABLE >
<TR> <TH>  </TH> <TH> mpg </TH> <TH> cyl </TH> <TH> disp </TH>  </TR>
  <TR> <TD> Mazda RX4 </TD> <TD> 21.00 </TD> <TD> 6.00 </TD> <TD> 160.00 </TD> </TR>
  <TR> <TD> Mazda RX4 Wag </TD> <TD> 21.00 </TD> <TD> 6.00 </TD> <TD> 160.00 </TD> </TR>
  <TR> <TD> Datsun 710 </TD> <TD> 22.80 </TD> <TD> 4.00 </TD> <TD> 108.00 </TD> </TR>
   </TABLE>
```

(which could be directed to a file with the `file` argument to `print.xtable` as in the previous example.)

Comment: I look at `?xtable` and there is no `type` parameter for me. When I specify it it is ignored, I always get LaTeX. It only works when I `x <- xtable(...)` and then use `print.xtable(x, type="html")`.

Comment: @Someone The `type` argument *is* an argument to the `print` call, not the `xtable` call. I just nested the `xtable` call inside the `print` call for convenience.

Answer (score 8):

You could also have a look at the `tableHTML` package, that was developed for this reason.

```
library(tableHTML)
mtcars %>%
  tableHTML()
```

And to print the HTML on the console:

```
tableHTML(mtcars[1:2, 1:3]) %>% 
  print(viewer = FALSE)

# <table style="border-collapse:collapse;" class=table_9302 border=1>
#   <thead>
#   <tr>
#   <th id="tableHTML_header_1"> </th>
#   <th id="tableHTML_header_2">mpg</th>
#   <th id="tableHTML_header_3">cyl</th>
#   <th id="tableHTML_header_4">disp</th>
#   </tr>
#   </thead>
#   <tbody>
#   <tr>
#   <td id="tableHTML_rownames">Mazda RX4</td>
#   <td id="tableHTML_column_1">21</td>
#   <td id="tableHTML_column_2">6</td>
#   <td id="tableHTML_column_3">160</td>
#   </tr>
#   <tr>
#   <td id="tableHTML_rownames">Mazda RX4 Wag</td>
#   <td id="tableHTML_column_1">21</td>
#   <td id="tableHTML_column_2">6</td>
#   <td id="tableHTML_column_3">160</td>
#   </tr>
#   </tbody>
#   </table>
```

The table can also be styled with CSS using the `add_css_` family of functions, if needed.

Details of the package and tutorials (vignettes) are [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/index.html)

Comment: I really like this package. Makes it quite easy to incorporate dataframe into HTML to be sent as an email. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 6):

```
to_html_table<-function(dataframe){
 tags$table(
  tags$thead(tags$tr(lapply(colnames(dataframe), function(x) tags$th(x)))),
  tags$tbody(
   apply(dataframe,1, function(x) { tags$tr(lapply(x, function(y) tags$td(y)))})
  ))
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add an explanation. Code-only answers are discouraged and may be deleted because they don't explain anything.

Comment: [As part of the review system](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18708495), I edited your answer to fix the formatting. You should listen to WebDevBooster and explain your code.

Comment: Not my answer, but the code uses a package called htmltools. What's nice about this answer is that the resulting HTML ends up in a variable, rather than in a file. This makes it super-easy to use in the context of Shiny, which also auto-installs htmltools.

Comment: I suspect that this uses shiny. This alone is not a reproducible function and thus isn't a complete answer.

Answer (score 5):

A prettier but slower option:

```
library(htmlTable)
htmlTable(iris)
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is actually quite simple, if you use xtable. (Thanks to Señor O for the tip.)

```
 install.packages("xtable")
 library(xtable)
 out_table_x <- xtable(out_table)
 print(out_table_x, type='html', file="./example.html")
```