# How to create a table on a Stack Overflow question/answer from a R dataframe object?

Tags: r, formatting

I am aware of the syntax to [create a table on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow), but is there any function that takes a dataframe as argument and that copies the table to the clipboard, so that it can be pasted on Stack Overflow?

```r
# Any function that takes a dataframe as an argument 
# and that copies the table to the clipboard
table_to_clipboard(df) # ???

# Then I could paste the result (Ctrl + V)

|      Heading 1      |     Heading 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |
|          99         |         42       |
```

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 |
| 99 | 42 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I turn an R data frame into a simple, unstyled html table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748566/how-can-i-turn-an-r-data-frame-into-a-simple-unstyled-html-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get such a table with the help of the **pander** package:

```
dat <- iris[1:3, ]
library(pander)
pandoc.table(dat, style = "rmarkdown")

| Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | Petal.Width | Species |
|:------------:|:-----------:|:------------:|:-----------:|:-------:|
|     5.1      |     3.5     |     1.4      |     0.2     | setosa  |
|     4.9      |      3      |     1.4      |     0.2     | setosa  |
|     4.7      |     3.2     |     1.3      |     0.2     | setosa  |
```

| Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | Petal.Width | Species |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.1 | 3.5 | 1.4 | 0.2 | setosa |
| 4.9 | 3 | 1.4 | 0.2 | setosa |
| 4.7 | 3.2 | 1.3 | 0.2 | setosa |

To get it in the clipboard:

```
library(clipr)
write_clip(pandoc.table.return(dat, style = "rmarkdown"))
```